# UITextView Link To iTunes Using Word Rather Than Address

Tags: uitextview, hyperlink

I'm trying to write a bio in a textview and want the names of cd's to link to the corresponding iTunes link. Is this possible? I don't want to put a long link address in the middle of a bio every time I mention a cd. Any help would be appreciated. And I think you can do it in a web view but I would rather use a textview to enter my text. I am not real familiar with html coding so this might be easy. Please help! :)

Comment: Well, I don't know how to do that using `UITextView`, but you can do it in `HTML` saying `<a href="LINK">TEXT TO DISPLAY</a>`. That's `HTML`. Don't forget to replace `LINK` with the link of course and `TEXT TO DISPLAY` with the required text to be displayed. You may make a method that lets the URL be something like (`stackoverflow/quest...`). I don't know if it's already implemented, actually

Comment: Thank you! I tried inserting that into the text view but it just displays the whole thing. I'm wondering if I can store the href in a variable and inject that into the text view text? The search continues! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to do what I wanted so I went ahead and used HTML. It was not as hard as I thought it would be. Thank you TheNavigator!

Comment: Have you been able to inject it? I just wanna know too :)

Comment: No, I just made an HTML doc and put it in a webview. I didn't realize it would be that easy and give me a lot more flexibility. I can change the hyperlink colors, something you are unable to do in a textview, and format it easier. If you would like some code snippets just let me know. :)